# Regex make a group optional

Tags: python, regex

I have the below messages to parse

```
Messages discarded due to Dispatch Queue cap: 0 / 60001 ms
Dispatch Queue size: 2
Dispatched Messages: 369 / 60001 ms
Dispatched message size: Average: 723, Entries: 39, Min: 366, Max: 1570
WinSockDispatcher: 53 / 8865 ms
UXDispatcher: 57 / 8865 ms
```

The regex which I have so far is

```
(Messages discarded.* Dispatch Queue cap|Dispatch Queue size|Dispatched Messages|WinSockDispatcher|UXDispatcher).+ (\d.+).+ (\d.+)
```

I am able to match almost everything I except the line

Dispatch Queue size: 2

Looks like the last group in my regex should be optional. I tried using `?` but I am unable to figure out the proper syntax.

Can someone please suggest the change that would be help here?

Comment: I don't know what to suggest beyond `?`.

Comment: Probably *everything* after the second to last group needs to be optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the groups:

```
(Messages discarded.* Dispatch Queue cap|Dispatch Queue size|Dispatched Messages|WinSockDispatcher|UXDispatcher): (\d+)(?: \/ +(\d+.*))?
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just using `re.split` to split on the colon and make a dict?

Like so:

```
txt='''\
Messages discarded due to Dispatch Queue cap: 0 / 60001 ms
Dispatch Queue size: 2
Dispatched Messages: 369 / 60001 ms
Dispatched message size: Average: 723, Entries: 39, Min: 366, Max: 1570
WinSockDispatcher: 53 / 8865 ms
UXDispatcher: 57 / 8865 ms''' 

import re 
data=dict(re.split(r':[ \t]*', l, maxsplit=1) for l in txt.splitlines())

>>> data
{'Messages discarded due to Dispatch Queue cap': '0 / 60001 ms', 
 'Dispatch Queue size': '2', 
 'Dispatched Messages': '369 / 60001 ms', 
 'Dispatched message size': 'Average: 723, Entries: 39, Min: 366, Max: 1570',
 'WinSockDispatcher': '53 / 8865 ms', 
 'UXDispatcher': '57 / 8865 ms'}
```

Then access any by key:

```
 >>> data['UXDispatcher']
 '57 / 8865 ms'
```

With this type of approach, you can then decode the integers and keep with the string for either presentation or program use:

```
data={}

for k,v in dict(re.split(r':[ \t]*', l, maxsplit=1) 
                            for l in txt.splitlines()).items():
    data[k]=(v,)+tuple(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', v)))

>>> data
{'Messages discarded due to Dispatch Queue cap': ('0 / 60001 ms', 0, 60001), 
 'Dispatch Queue size': ('2', 2), 
 'Dispatched Messages': ('369 / 60001 ms', 369, 60001), 
 'Dispatched message size': ('Average: 723, Entries: 39, Min: 366, Max: 1570', 723, 39, 366, 1570), 
 'WinSockDispatcher': ('53 / 8865 ms', 53, 8865), 
 'UXDispatcher': ('57 / 8865 ms', 57, 8865)}
```

Comment: I am finally adding everything to dictionary. But I guess I am doing in more primitive and non pythonic way I suppose. This is much better! Thank you!